# Getting Error JAR_SIG_NO_MANIFEST: Missing META-INF/MANIFEST.MF when pushing an apk file

Tags: android, xamarin, apk

I am a new developer, I was built an application Android and pushing to google play and appear an error when I pushing a APK file.
It takes 5 days, but not fix this error.
I use visual studio 2017 (xamarin).

Error:

> You uploaded an APK with an invalid signature (learn more about signing). Error from apksigner: ERROR: JAR_SIG_NO_MANIFEST: Missing META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

Comment: you need to sign the APK before uploading them into the Playstore. In  Androidstudio build -> Generate signed APK.

Comment: I use Visual studio 2017, I not use AndroidStudio, thanks. How to sign by VS 2017?

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 61):

Make sure you mark both v1(jar Signature) and V2(full APK signature)

**EDIT:** By the way, the reason for it to fail if you sign with v2 only, is that v2 was introduced in Android 7.0 (sdk 24) and you are probably targeting an older `minSdkVersion`.
Therefore, if you target `minSdkVersion 23` or below, you need to use signing schemes v1 AND v2 (or only v1), because if the app is installed on Android 6.0 or older, it can only be verified through v1 scheme.
If you target `minSdkVersion 24` or above, then you can use v2 on its own, since the app won't be installed on older versions.
You can also check this poorly noted on [Android Docs](https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v2), third paragraph.

Comment: This helped me. I clicked only v2 signing without giving a though for it. I wonder why v1 is not default checked, if it's mandatory?

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks for sharing this. To say the Android development tools are second-tier user experiences is an understatement.

Comment: This fixed for me

Comment: Thank you, this has helped me to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Follow this process.

select the menu option Build > Package YourAppName.apk

This will create two .apk files in the bin/Release folder.

1.mono.samples.YourAppName-Signed.APK // Deploy this APK in Playstore.
2.mono.samples.YourAppName.APK

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2017, not AndroidStudio

Comment: This code is for Visual studio only. refer this [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2_-_signing_the_android_application_package/visual-studio-xa-4.2.5-and-earlier/)

Comment: TeamViewer: ID: 235 606 766, Pass: 8231, please

Comment: I get Error from apksigner: ERROR: JAR_SIG_NO_MANIFEST: Missing META-INF/MANIFEST.MF. I can deploy my signed APK to my phones with no issues. The VS project contains a Manifest. What is the problem? I've been trying to upload for several days.